# What is wrong with this <select> menu

Tags: html, tags

So I have a, no doubt, simple problem, but it has me fairly stumped as to what the problem is.  I am using a jQuery function to append a `<li>` to the `<ul>`.  It is all going as planned except that the drop-down `<select>` menu isn't showing me any options.  It merely displays the first `<option>` and never gives me any other options.  I feel like its something very simple, but I can't seem to find where the problem is.  Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for the help.

```
$('#courses').append('<li class="plan" ><table width="100%" ><tr><td>'+fallNamesArray[i]+' Credit Hours: '+fallNamesArray[i]+' Grade: </td><td align="right"><select id="grd" style="width:20px" data-mini="true" ><option>A</option><option>A-</option><option>B+</option><option>B</option><option>B-</option><option>C+</option><option>C</option><option>C-</option><option>D</option><option>E</option></select></td><td><input type="submit" value="Add Course" data-mini="true" /></td><td align="right"><input type = "button" class="del" value="Delete" data-icon="delete" data-mini="true" data-inline ="true" data-iconpos="right" /></td></tr></table></li>').listview('refresh');
```

By the way, I apologize about the "run-on line."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `width:20px` from the select's style or increase it.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/FyEU4/)**